# In EF 4.1 eager loading, how can I load multiple (same-level) grandchild relationships?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I'm seemingly stumped by a likely simple solution. I've typically used lazy loading in EF 4.1, and I'm now trying to use eager loading in my application so I can use the built-in JSON serializer without issues. The problem I am having is that I can't figure out how to use .Include() to load multiple same-level grandchild relationships.

```
public class Canvas
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ContentArea> Contents { get; set; }
}

public class ContentArea
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int CanvasID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<TextContent> TextContents { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ImageContent> ImageContents { get; set; }
}

public class TextContent
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ContentAreaID { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int Color { get; set; }
}

public class ImageContent
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ContentAreaID { get; set; }
    public string Filename { get; set; }
}
```

I've tried the following with no success. How can I write the loading code to load TextContents and ImageContents?

Doesn't compile:

```
var c = dataContext.Canvases
        .Include(ca => ca.Contents.Select(co => co.ImageContents).Select(co => co.TextContents))
        .FirstOrDefault();
```

Doesn't work, second Include overrides first:

```
var c = dataContext.Canvases
        .Include(ca => ca.Contents.Select(co => co.ImageContents))
        .Include(ca => ca.Contents.Select(co => co.TextContents))
        .FirstOrDefault();
```

Doesn't work, throws runtime exception:

```
var c = dataContext.Canvases
        .Include(ca => ca.Contents.Select(co => new { co.ImageContents, co.TextContents }))
        .FirstOrDefault();
```

Edit:

I've given up on this approach for now and just made view models based on some other articles and approaches they have taken solving the "serializing Entity models" problem with the ASP.NET MVC built in JSON serialization. This caused me to duplicate my classes, but it was made easy by using the AutoMapper library to transfer all of the data back and forth automatically.

Comment: For the #3, What is the exception? For #2, i think it should work properly, what is result? co.ImageContents is null?

Comment: For #2 the result is null. Below someone is saying it is working, but I forgot to include I'm not actually testing by pulling the entire list of all objects but I'm using a .Where() clause and pulling a single record with .FirstOrDefault(). The unusual exception I receive with #3 is "The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.
Parameter name: path".

Comment: What does your `.Where()` look like?

Comment: .Where(c => c.ID = 2039) -- just pulling a single record via the PK ala lazy loading dataContext.Object.Find(id)

Answer (score 3):

I have succeeded with following codes

```
var contents = db.Canvases
                 .Include(c=>c.Contents.Select(co=>co.TextContents))
                 .Include(c=>c.Contents.Select(co=>co.ImageContents))
                 .ToList();
```

Comment: Does this also work for you when using a .Where() clause and pulling a single record? I'm stumped that it is working for you and not for me. In my case, when I use this style of query, either TextContents or ImageContents is ending up as null. What is even more confusing to me is that the same element is ending up as null even if I switch the order of the .Include statements.

Comment: You can add a Where clause to this, but you can only filter on items that exist on the Canvases entity.  That is, after the second .Include you could add .Where(c => c.Name == "Foo"), but you can't filter on anything in the Contents, TextContents or ImageContents collections - it's not supported by EF.

Comment: That being said, you can filter on items in the Contents, TextContents, and ImageContents collections after calling ToList(), but by then you've already retrieved all of the data from the database, even the data you want to filter out, and thus the filtering is done in memory.